# How do I install SQLite for use in a Universal Windows App targetting UAP v10

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I'm trying to get SQLite working in a Universal Windows App targeting UAP v10 using Visual Studio 2015 (RTM).

I've installed the Visual Studio Extension, "SQLite for Universal App Platform" and referenced it (and "Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows Platform Apps") from my project.

I've then added System.Data.SQLite via NuGet, which appears to work as a reference to it gets added to my project and I don't see any error messages. However, I don't appear to get any DLLs added to my project through this process.

Upon further investigation, it looks as though the System.Data.SQLite NuGet package is actually empty, but lists the following as dependencies...

1. System.Data.SQLite.Core
2. System.Data.SQLite.Linq
3. System.Data.SQLite.EF6

So - I tried adding each one of these through the Package Manager Console and received the following error...

> Install-Package : System.Data.SQLite.Core 1.0.98.1 is not compatible
>   with UAP,Version=v10.0.

This seems like a fairly conclusive error message. So what do I do now... is SQLite actually supported for Windows 10 Universal Apps at the moment or not? Documentation I can find on the web seems pretty contradictory or at least seems to imply that I should be able to do what I'm trying to do.

Any help / pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to install  http://sqlite.org/2015/sqlite-uap-3081101.vsix

Comment: @Shahriar Yes - That's installed and successfully referenced in my project - it's the System.Data.SQLite package that I can't get to install.

Answer (score 3):

Win10 UWP(UAP) and Win8.1/WP8.1 Store App does not support ADO. System.Data.SQL  is an ADO provider, then it's not applicable for UWP, I believe.

To using SQLite on UWP, you need to have SQLite itself and wrapper for .NET.

SQLite - [SQLite (Visual Studio Extension)](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4913e7d5-96c9-4dde-a1a1-69820d615936)

SQLite wrapper for .NET (NuGet) - [SQLite.Net-PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/)
or [SQLite.Net.Async-PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net.Async-PCL/)

And, following link may helps you. It's a VB guy's blog =) but very insightful for uwp works.

[Win10 apps in .NET - references](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2015/06/01/win10-apps-in-net-references.aspx)

Edited 7 Feb 2017: Windows 10 Anniversary Update(1607) support the SQLite as "Microsoft.Data.SQLite".

[Using SQLite databases in UWP apps - Windows blog](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/02/06/using-sqlite-databases-uwp-apps/)

Comment: System.Data is available for UWP, though I don't know of any providers that actually support it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Microsoft is building a version. As of this comment, they are in release candidate 1.

https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite

Answer (score 0):

go to http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki and download the right installer for the .net framework youre using.

this will register the dll's for you and give you everything you need

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see an appropriate download on there - I believe I need a .NET Core version for Windows 10 UAP?

Comment: I believe that this would be installed as part of any of the installer \ setup versions.

Comment: Alternatively, you can grab the 7Mb download of the empty nuget package from that link too and ensure that the assemblies you need are actually in there

Answer (score 0):

Since the Windows 10 Anniversary Update (Build 14393), SQLite has also shipped as part of the Windows SDK

This link explains everything:

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/02/06/using-sqlite-databases-uwp-apps

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is supported for Universal Windows platform.

**C# solution**

1. Install [SQLite for Universal Windows Platform](https://sqlite.org/2017/sqlite-uwp-3210000.vsix) Visual Studio extension.
2. Use SQLite C# API Wrapper [Microsoft.Data.SQLite](https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/). More information [here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/02/06/using-sqlite-databases-uwp-apps).

**C# or C++/CX solution**

1. Install [SQLite for Universal Windows Platform](https://sqlite.org/2017/sqlite-uwp-3210000.vsix) Visual Studio extension.
2. Add reference to SQLite for Universal Windows Platform extension to your project:

> Project => References => Universal Windows => Extensions => SQLite for
>   Universal Windows Platform

3. Write your own wrapper using [low-level SQLite API](https://sqlite.org/cintro.html) in C# or C++.

**C++/CX solution**

This [SQLite-WinRT](https://sqlwinrt.codeplex.com) wrapper is handy for UWP apps written in C++/CX.